# How to use or with variables in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
size?: 'standart' | 'large';
```

then I made constants like:

```
export const INPUT_SIZE_LARGE: string = 'large';
export const INPUT_SIZE_STANDART: string = 'standart';
```

But this doesn't work:

```
size?: INPUT_SIZE_LARGE | INPUT_SIZE_STANDART;
```

Why? How can i deal with it?

Comment: Why not make an actual type, `type InputSize = "standart" | "large"`?

Comment: `'standard' | 'large'` is a type definition that is used at compile time, it's not outputed in the resulting javascript. constants are actually used in the resulting javascript. Therefore you can't use a constant in a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to remove type `string`, because it enforces TypeScript to widening type from `'large'` to `string`. Second you need to use `typeof` keyword. There is different keyword `typeof` for JavaScript and TypeScript. In Typescript it extracts type from value.

Here is working code:

```js
export const INPUT_SIZE_LARGE = 'large';
export const INPUT_SIZE_STANDART = 'standart';

type A = {
  size?: typeof INPUT_SIZE_LARGE | typeof INPUT_SIZE_STANDART;
}
```

Here is working code in TS playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wJIDkAKBVAFQH0BlDALQFEiAZAQQCUBxSuAXjgHIAbAQygDmwTgG4AUKEixEKdHGz5iZKqQJ0sAEUYF2XdL2QATfjFFixMAJ5hgcOroDeYuHFQBLAF7AA-AC44VjYQAGbyuISkFNT0zKwAPgHWwCFhipEqJGqa2uIAvkA

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly, you are assigning a value to a type. which is not appropriate.

```
export const INPUT_SIZE_LARGE = 'large';
export const INPUT_SIZE_STANDART = 'standart';

type size = typeof INPUT_SIZE_LARGE | typeof INPUT_SIZE_STANDART;
```

but this gonna work

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains what's wrong:

> 'INPUT_SIZE_LARGE' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof INPUT_SIZE_LARGE'? (2749)

Separately from that, you're explicitly typing your constants as being `string`, but if you want them to be a string literal type you can use for `size`, you need to let them be string literal types, not `string`s.

So removing `:string` and adding `typeof` solves it:

```typescript
export const INPUT_SIZE_LARGE = 'large';
export const INPUT_SIZE_STANDART = 'standart';

interface X {
    size?: typeof INPUT_SIZE_LARGE | typeof INPUT_SIZE_STANDART;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wJIDkAKBVAFQH0BlDALQFEiAZAQQCUBxSuAXjgHIAbAQygDmwTgG4AUKEixEKdHGz5iZKqQJ0sAEUYF2XdL2QATfjFFixAS2QxgUAGa8EwOAA04AbzFxvcVBYBewAD8AFxwMACeYMAQdvK4hKQU1PTMrAA+4VExcQqJytQkapra4gC+YkA)

I thought you might need `as const` as well, but you don't.